# Is there any online tool where students can register for tasks/assignments?

Tags: teaching, website, tools

I'm teaching architecture and I want my students to select a building that they will work with from a list. When a building is selected by one student, it should no longer be an option for the others (first come - first serve).

Is there an online tool where a list can be created and students can select their object of interest, preferably without going through a whole registration process?
Our student-platform unfortunately does not offer this functionality.
Any suggestions?

Tool could be in English or German.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the tool "Doodle" ([doodle.com](http://doodle.com)) where a poll can be set up with different options to fit my needs. With this tool, appointments can also be arranged.

Here's a link to an example I set up: [select architect](http://doodle.com/eurfcv2ua6xwxz5h)